# Чем заменить mysql_result в PHP 7.3

Tags: php7

```
$connect=mysqli_connect("$host", "$user", "$pass", $db) or die("Ошибка подключения");

mysqli_query($connect, "SET NAMES utf8");

$result = mysqli_query($connect,"SELECT * ......"); //Запрос сократил намерянно

for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++)
 {
  $razdel = mysql_result($result,$i,'razdel'); //Чем заменить?
  echo '$razdel';
  echo '<br/>';
}
```

Comment: Может `mysqli_result()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Dikkly Вы используете mysqli
Соответственно

```
$razdel = mysqli_result($result,$i,'razdel');
```

Но данный синтаксис изначально не корректен.

Если вопрос в том, как обрабатывать ответ без $i++, то

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $razdel = $row["razdel"];
    echo $razdel;
    echo '<br/>';
}
```

Если хотите именно для первых 10 записей, или с подсчётом количества именно через $i++, то

```
$query = "SELECT ...."; // запрос в БД
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
$result = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
$Numrows = mysqli_num_rows($result); // Считаем количество данных в ответе.
for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++){ //Для первых 10 записей
    $razdel = $result[$i]["razdel"];
    echo $razdel;
    echo '<br/>';
}

for ($i = 0; $i < $Numrows; $i++){ //Для всех записей
    $razdel = $result[$i]["razdel"];
    echo $razdel;
    echo '<br/>';
}
```

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysqli_result()

Comment: Используйте только вторую часть, где начинается с while. В первой части уточнение, что надо использовать mysqli вместо mysql. У Вас уже есть получение параметра result в $result = mysqli_query($connect,"SELECT * ......"); А получение раздела в примере $razdel = $row["razdel"];